# jquery ajax pass data which has multiple value with the same key

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a easy way to build an ajax query like this with jquery?

```
http://www.test.com/?value=happy&value=good&value=day
```

I tried

```
$.getJSON('http://www.test.com/', {'value': ['happy','good','day']});
```

but the result becomes `http://www.test.com/?value[]=happy&value[]=good&value[]=day`

Comment: There's no logic in that kind of request.
How would you access each and every value if they all have the same key?

Comment: it can be access. for example, I am using google appengine and there is a function called get_all https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get_all

Comment: @OfirBaruch On the server-side you'd get an array of the values.

Comment: I'd also like to get rid of the brackets…

Comment: No logic in that kind of request?  That's the HTML standard way of passing values from a 'select mutiple'.  The 'select' tag has only one name (e.g. 'fieldname'), and so when multiple values are selected, they come through exactly like that... 'fieldname=1&fieldname=2&fieldname=3'.  In ASP.NET MVC controller, those values would come in as a string array in a parameter named 'fieldname'.  If you made 'fieldname' parameter a string instead of an array, then MVC would just join them all into a single comma-separated string with all the values for 'fieldname'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for anyone who comes here through search, you can use the `traditional` [parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param) to `$.ajax` and set it to `true` then you will get:

`http://www.test.com/?value=happy&value=good&value=day`.

Answer (score -1):

This url seems to be good:

```
http://www.test.com/?value[]=happy&value[]=good&value[]=day
```

in php you can access the values like an array

Comment: Who care about what PHP does? I don't want square brackets in my requests, how can I build such a request with jQuery?

Comment: Like @alartur said, that's work for PHP for sure, but totally doesn't for ASP.