# jquery ajax data object with multiple values for the same key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to make an ajax call, and in the data object I need to have several values in the same key.

```
var data = {
    foo: "bar",
    foo: "baz"
}

$.ajax({
    url: http://example.com/APIlocation,
    data: data,
    success: function (results) { console.log(results) },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

The intention is to get a URL that looks something like:

```
http://example.com/APIlocation?foo=bar&foo=baz
```

I tried structuring the data like this:

```
var data = {
    foo: ["bar","baz"]
}
```

Which unsurprisingly, did not work because it encodes the url like this:

```
http://example.com/APILocation?foo%5B%5D=bar&foo%5B%5D=baz
```

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11915831/jquery-ajax-pass-data-which-has-multiple-value-with-the-same-key), but could not make it work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `$.param` to convert an array to a parameter string that contains the same key multiple times. Set the second argument to `true` so it doesn't get url-encoded, and then just pass that string to the data property in the AJAX call:

```
var data = $.param({ foo: ['bar', 'baz'] }, true);
// data is now 'foo=bar&foo=baz'

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/APIlocation',
    data: data, // Will handle the string correctly.
    success: function (results) { console.log(results) },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Or, with an object, you can set the `traditional` property to `true`:

```
var data = {
    foo: ["bar","baz"]
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/APIlocation',
    data: data,
    success: function (results) { console.log(results) },
    dataType: 'json',
    traditional: true
});
```

Comment: Using jquery.param() gives me a URL like: http://example.com/APIlocation?foo=foo%3Dbar%26foo%3Dbaz

Comment: Setting the traditional property to true on the ajax call worked. Thank you.

Comment: For `jQuery.param` to work, you need to pass `true` as the second argument.
I'm glad this worked for you, no problem.

Comment: (the second argument to `jQuery.param` is also `traditional`)